# how to display select dropdown depend on previous select?

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, drop-down-menu

I want to display second select if first select is "Professor" and if select is "Student" not display second dropdown.
html:

```js
function privilegija() {
  privilegija = document.getElementById("permisija5")
  predmeti = document.getElementById("predmeti")
  if (privilegija === "Student") {
    predmeti.display = "none"
  } else if (privilegija === "Professor") {
    predmeti.display = "block"
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="permisija">Privilegija</label>
<select class="permisija" id="permisija5" name="permisija5" required>
  <option>Professor</option>
  <option>Student</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div id="predmeti">
  <select name="predmet">
    <option>Matematika</option>
    <option>Engleski</option>
    <option>Programiranje</option>
    <option>Operativni sistemi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You did not call your function - I would not recommend calling it inline in the onchange
- You did not compare the `value` of the select

I would use eventListeners and a class

Note: You can hide the div from the start or toggle on load

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the elements on the page has loaded
  const predmeti = document.getElementById("predmeti");
  const permisija = document.getElementById("permisija5");
  const toggle = () => predmeti.classList.toggle("hide", permisija.value === "Student");
  permisija.addEventListener("change", toggle);
  toggle(); // when the page loads
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="permisija">Privilegija</label>
<select class="permisija" id="permisija5" name="permisija5" required>
  <option>Professor</option>
  <option selected>Student</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div id="predmeti" class="hide">
  <select name="predmet">
    <option>Matematika</option>
    <option>Engleski</option>
    <option>Programiranje</option>
    <option>Operativni sistemi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to acess the actual value of the dropdown. Currently you're comparing the dropdown element to a string, which will always be false.

```
if (privilegija.value === "Student") {
    predmeti.display = "none"
} else if (privilegija.value === "Professor") {
    predmeti.display = "" // No value needed, will return to default
}
```

(This is of course assuming you did call your function, see other answers in case that is a concern as well)

Answer (score 0):

This puts into account if no selection would be made on load

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

privilegija = document.getElementById("permisija5")
predmeti = document.getElementById("predmeti");

show(); // show or hide on page load

function show() {
if (privilegija.value === "Student") {
    predmeti.style.display = "none"
  } else if (privilegija.value === "Professor") {
    predmeti.style.display = "block"
  }
  }


privilegija.addEventListener("change", () => {
  show(); // show or hide on select change
})
});
```

```html
<label for="permisija">Privilegija</label>
<select  class="permisija"  id="permisija5" name="permisija5" required>
<option>Professor</option>
<option>Student</option>

  
  
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div id="predmeti" style="display: none">
  <select name="predmet">
    <option>Matematika</option>
    <option>Engleski</option>
    <option>Programiranje</option>
    <option>Operativni sistemi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Working with the code you've started, you can trigger your function when the user selects something by adding a change handler:

```
<select class="permisija" id="permisija5" name="permisija5" onchange="privilegija()" required>
```

Then, a few changes to your function so you are getting the right value and setting the right css

```
function privilegija() {
  privilegija = document.getElementById("permisija5")
  predmeti = document.getElementById("predmeti")
  if (privilegija.value === "Student") {
    predmeti.style.display = "none"
  } else if (privilegija.value === "Professor") {
    predmeti.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```